# PowerShell 2.0 command equivalent to PowerShell 3.0 Get-Content -Raw

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am currently working on a code snippet to convert AS3 files to JS.
Below is my script.

```
$source = "sample.as"
$dest = "modifiedScript.js"
$raw1 = Get-Content -Path $source | Out-String
$raw1 -replace "extends.*?({)", '{' | Set-Content $dest
```

`Sample.as`:

```
class EquivalentFraction extends MainClass 
{

    // other codes
    function f1(){

    }
}
```

I am trying to get the output like this (replace whatever comes between `extends` and `{` by `{`):

```
class EquivalentFraction
{
    // other codes
    function f1(){

    }
}
```

The above code does not work if the opening brace is present in next line.
As I am using PowerShell 2.0, I am unable to use `Get-Content -Raw` to get the contents without lines.
After searching, I came to know that I have to use `Out-String` instead of `-Raw` switch.
But it's not working.

Answer (score 5):

The PowerShell v2 equivalent for `Get-Content -Raw` is `Get-Content | Out-String`. The reason why your code doesn't do what you expect has nothing to do with the data import.

You don't get the expected result because of the regular expression you're using. `.` matches any single character **except newlines**. Since your data has the opening curly bracket on the line *after* the line with the `extends` keyword you do have a newline between `extends` and `{`, meaning that `extends.*?({)` will never match.

You can resolve this by using `[\s\S]` (match any whitespace and any non-whitespace)

```
$raw1 -replace 'extends[\s\S]*?{', '{'
```

or by using the "single line mode" option (which makes `.` match newlines as well)

```
$raw1 -replace '(?s)extends.*?{', '{'
```